# Mysql read speed

Tags: mysql

How fast can a single physical Mysql instance run the following query on a 2 column table that has about 100GB?

```
SELECT short_url FROM long_to_short WHERE long_url = :in_long_url
```

I recognize this still leaves out a few important aspects - indexes / DB settings etc. I would truly appreciate a breakdown by the various flavors.

Do you know how this would change if we *tiered* storage (SSD + mechanicals)?

Comment: It certainly does. You need to state for a start how the table is indexed. The speed depends on the table definition of *your* table, speed of *your* disks, *your* processor, the amount of memory available in *your* computer, and the configuration *you* have defined for MySQL. Question is also off topic.